# Custom Intl.Collators?

Tags: javascript, unicode, internationalization, collation, ecmascript-intl

Is it possible to create a custom [`Intl.Collator`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Collator) object for Javascript? Suppose I have:

```
var letters = [ "a", "n", "ñ", "x" ]
```

If I sort them, the `ñ` will go to the end by default:

```
letters.sort() // [ "a", "n", "x", "ñ" ]
```

However, using the new `Intl.Collator`, I can do:

```
letters.sort(Intl.Collator('es').compare)
```

Which sorts by Spanish (`es`) rules, and puts the `ñ` after `n`.

```
[ "a", "n", "ñ", "x" ]
```

Now, suppose for some reason I wanted to write a `Collator` of my own, that would put the `ñ` first?

```
[ "ñ", "a", "n", "x" ]
```

I haven’t been able to find any information about customizing a new rule set for `Intl.Collator`.

Is this possible?

**Update**

Yes, it is possible.

Update:

I have found advice in the ECMAscript i18n standard[2](http://norbertlindenberg.com/2012/12/ecmascript-internationalization-api/index.html#Subclasses) on how to create custom locales:

```js
function MyCollator​(locales, options) {
  Intl​.Collator​.call​(this, locales, options);
  // initialize MyCollator properties
}
MyCollator​.prototype = Object​.create​(Intl​.Collator​.prototype);
MyCollator​.prototype​.constructor = MyCollator;
// add methods to MyCollator​.prototype
var collator = new MyCollator​("de-u-co-phonebk");
a​.sort​(collator​.compare);
```

Comment: Do you want to define an arbitrary order for arbitrary symbols?

Comment: I recently made a new [tag:ecmascript-intl] for questions like this but don't want to assume myself which of your current tags it should replace. Use it if you wish.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to get what you want by using the "sensitivity" option.

The `Intl.Collator.prototype` is not writable.

You may be able to create and array with sort and character to set you own sort order.

```
$convert[character]= sortOrder ;
```

Array structure would depend on purpose.
 
With this structure you'd have to convert the result back again.

```
$letters = [$convert[a],$convert[n],$convert[ñ],$convert[x]);
```

This one would probably work best in most cases.

```
$letters = [[$convert[a],a],[$convert[n],n],[$convert[ñ],[ñ],[$convert[x],x]);
```